# jQuery contents append code is not working

Tags: jquery

jQuery need content append to another html tag , my code is not working

```
<li>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="overview">this is text</div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
</li>

$('li').each(function(){

    var des = $('.content .overview',this).text();
    $ ('.content .overview',this)contents().appendTo($('.content p'));
    console.log(des)

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daBYQ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$('li').each(function(){

```
var des = $('.content .overview',this).text();
$ ('.content .overview',this).contents().appendTo($('.content p'));
console.log(des)
```

});

you missed "." .contents()

Answer (score 4):

You can do this much easier:

```
$(".content p").text(function(){
    return $(this).prev().text();   
});​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daBYQ/2/

jQuery will natively perform an implicit loop over the matched elements, and the `.text` method permits us to pass it an anonymous function from which we can grab the text content of the earlier siblings to the current paragraph being handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(){    
    var des = $('.content .overview',this).text();
    $ ('.content .overview',this).contents().appendTo($('.content p'));
    console.log(des)    
});
```